# to rewrite or not to rewrite

Tags: scale

so I need to maintain this old legacy project, where one part of it is amaturely written with Wordpess, lots of crappy custom plugins, lots of ducktaped scripts, that solve one or other problem, database is designed very very purely too, there is also other part written with Zend, which is thightly connected with WP part, there is also this other "masterpiece" project connected to first project data. Main table contains around 1.5M records and needs to be normalized too. now this big ball of nails "works", also it has lots of LOCs, which are result of bad foundations, so it is a huge pain to maintain. Thing is, the way I see this, by not rewriting we are loosing on the long term, because we lose flexibility both from technology and busi
ness perspective,plus it starts not to scale, but rewriting is a risk, plus we would need to convert old data to new data structures. Hacker part of me wants to break this, take a risk and do it right, but at the same time I am having a feeling that my immaturity tries to take a too big bite at once. So what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like yours, 9 out of 10 times, I suggest to rewrite. Rationally, the situation a) won't get better, and b) will certainly get worse. You should bite the bullet before it's too late.

And by too late I mean something breaks completely and not only will you have to rewrite the whole thing, but your service will also be offline (ergo you may be also losing users/customers).

Answer (score 3):

In situations like yours, 9 out of 10 times people suggest a rewrite and they are wrong.

Unless you have great application level knowledge about what the system is doing you will not be able to rewrite it successfully, quickly.

If the system is working today, but is crappy in many ways, and you have management buy-in (they own the software) to "fix stuffs", then I suggest an incremental approach will often be better than a full-on rewrite.

I suspect that the database is giving you the most headaches, so that may be the best place to start.  Start by understanding the problem that it is currently solving and write that down.  If there is no layer between the software and the db (other than jdbc or the like) add a layer.  Once there is a layer separating the db from the application, it will be easier to change the db (and the layer) while minimizing the impact on the application.

At some point you will be happy with the first thing you changed.  At that point, fix some other part.  Repeat until the system is "more better".

Concerning risk:  Taking risks is not bad, but being careless is terrible.  Understand the risks and plan to mitigate them.

Comment: This would be my recommendation as well. In my career, I have seen many instances where a complete rewrite is favored by developers. However, there are lot of problems that are not typically thought about in this case. Here are few to considered (1) As DwB mentioned, Are you sure you have full understanding of the system? (2) How will you be sure there are no new bugs introduced? (3) What are your data migration plans? I am guess this is a live system and users are using it (4) What do you plan to do while data migration happens? Users are SOL? Incremental approach has best chance of success.

Answer (score 2):

A good strategy in this situations is to "strangle" your application as described by Martin Fowler:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerApplication.html

The strategy is to gradually create a new system around the edges of the old, letting it grow slowly over several years until the old system is strangled.
[image]

I already strangled a legacy application using this approach with great results and practically no offline time